# Second \*MPinclusions does not overwrite the first if some \*MPcode is present between them

Tags: context, metapost

As written in ConTeXt wiki, "second inclusion overwrites the first", i.e. this code

```
\startMPinclusions
path a;
a := fullcircle scaled 1cm;
\stopMPinclusions
\startMPinclusions
\stopMPinclusions
\startMPcode draw a; \stopMPcode
```

should produce no images, and it does, but the following code, with some MPcode between two MPinclusions:

```
\startMPinclusions
path a;
a := fullcircle scaled 1cm;
\stopMPinclusions
\startMPcode \stopMPcode
\startMPinclusions
\stopMPinclusions
\startMPcode draw a; \stopMPcode
```

produces a circle.
Is this a bug, and if it is, is there a fix for it? And if it's not, what is the right way to reset all the metapost stuff?

Comment: if your objective is just to set `a` to be undefined, you could just redeclare it with (say) `numeric a;`.  Redeclaring causes MP to forget about any previous definition.

Comment: i have many variables with arbitrary names, and i want them all to be undefined once i start new MPinclusions. of course, i can keep track of them all somehow, but that seems to be wrong way to do it.

Comment: I feel that this is a XY problem. Can you explain why you are trying to reset all MP variables? If you really want to do this, you should create a new MP instance.

Comment: i have a lot of metapost constructions, each using many variable names, so, for example, i want to be sure that when i'm making a typo in a variable name, metapost will show me an error, rather than use some irrelevant old variable of the same name. i thought \startMPinclusions will do that for me, but if i can't just reset everything without explicitly defining new instance, i guess, i'll try to do it that way, thank you

Comment: As for XY problem: \*MPinclusions block is meant (as described in the ConTeXt wiki) to contain code that will be used in the current MP instance and to be overwritten by following \*MPinclusions, so i didn't came up with this kind of use of \*MPinclusions as a solution to a problem, but rather found it to behave unexpectedly (i. e. not overwriting previous one), which seems like a problem on its own to me. On the other hand, \defineMPinstance is intended to define "custom MetaPost style with particular features", but i need no such thing, i need only variables and functions.